# Why does it sound so weird? (Beethoven quartet)

Tags: theory, harmony, analysis, consonance-and-dissonance

[image: fugal development]

Why does the first A# of the tetrachord of fugal development in op. 131, no. 7, m. 114 cello sound so weird? Is it because of the false relation with B?

Comment: I'm not seeing the false relation. Just to clarify: which A# are you looking at (measure / instrument)? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant A# of A# B C# D for bass. A# sounds weird but I don't know why.

Comment: What edition is this? The measure numbers aren't close to where I find this section. I ask, because there appears to be at least one error, but I can't confirm until I'm sure I'm comparing apples to apples.

Comment: I checked it out. I was listening to the score on YouTube, so I captured it right away, but when I listened to it again, I realized it was G, so I checked it and fixed it now. I apologize.

Comment: it was https://youtu.be/WlFYC1U5viw?t=2042

Comment: Thanks. It was the G#, but I also see my own mistake.

Comment: I presume that you've realized by now that the viola part is in alto clef, so there's no B.  But it seems like it ought to be said out loud, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no cross relation here. The A# consistently appears as the leading tone in B minor and is not contradicted by an A or Bb.

The "weird" sound, then, likely comes from one of two places:

1. The augmented second between the cello's preceding G and the A#. This is characteristic of a harmonic minor scale, but could be jarring if one isn't accustomed to the sound.
2. The root position A# diminished triad formed with the viola and violin II. Diminished triads are quite dissonant to begin with, and particularly in root position. This is augmented (pun most definitely intended) by the fact that the E is an octave above the A# and C#, making for an unusual voicing of the chord.